# Node.js JSON.parse(string) is returning a string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object as a string, I am parsing it with **JSON.parse()** but the resulting object is still a string. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var myString = "{Username:Brad,Password:12345}";

// adding in the quotes or else it throws an error saying 'unidentified token U
var myJson = JSON.parse('"' + myString + '"');

console.log(myJson.Username); // prints 'undefined'
console.log(typeof(myJson));  // prints 'string'
```

Comment: The string is not a valid representation of JSON. The keys and values should be wrapped in quotes. `var obj = JSON.parse('{"Username": "Brad","Password": "12345"}');` Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if your JSON is valid.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. Quotes were there in my client, and for some reason in the response in my server they disapeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not valid JSON. keys and strings need to be quoted:

```
var myString = '{"Username":"Brad","Password":12345}';
var myJson = JSON.parse( myString );
```

See json.org for information about JSON.

Comment: Ah ok that works, Thank you! I am using node http module for a server and a client. for some reason during the transit from client to server I am loosing the quotes.